# Coinbase API - Transactions

Tags: c#, coinbase-api

These are my temporary API settings:

```
wallet:accounts:read wallet:addresses:read wallet:buys:read wallet:checkouts:read wallet:contacts:read wallet:deposits:read wallet:notifications:read wallet:orders:read wallet:payment-methods:read wallet:sells:read wallet:transactions:read wallet:transactions:request wallet:transactions:send wallet:transactions:transfer wallet:user:read wallet:withdrawals:read
```

Reading account data:

```
HTTP REQUEST
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts

SCOPES
wallet:accounts:read
```

...  works well.

But the request of transactions data (I only need the buys as shown in the picture)...

[Coinbase Dashboard Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHeKV.png)

[Coinbase API Transactions](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#list-transactions)

```
HTTP REQUEST
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/transactions

SCOPES
wallet:transactions:read
```

... gives me an empty result:

```
{"pagination":{"ending_before":null,"starting_after":null,"limit":25,"order":"desc","previous_uri":null,"next_uri":null},"data":[]}
```

Anyone an idea what I could miss here?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you cannot get transactions. Let me tell; I've transactions on my BTC account. Retrieved and Sold BTC. When I call

```
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/account_id/transactions
```

with a `CB-VERSION` of `2018-05-09` (which is newly released), it returns. 
Be sure about;

1- You have transactions in your selected account. When you check from coinbase.com, be sure you are seeing transactions.

2- Be sure your account id is going to API with URL

3- Be sure selected account id is matches with sending account id.

3- Be sure your request headers are ok.

4- Be sure your Auth token is not expired.

I'm pretty sure that you're missing somethings in your code. If none of them above don't solve your problem, find me. I can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer - I got it.

My fault was to think I need to request my transactions for one and only account id, something like user id. But after reading the account JSON a little bit more accurate I found out that there is an account id for every wallet. I read out the EUR wallet where I have of course no single transaction.

Thanks anyway.
Sebastian.

Comment: you saved me a tonne of time.